# Zanzibar Open Ivr doest not accept sip invite?

Tags: java, asterisk

I'm sending a bottle at the sea with this question because this project is very old and no one use this now. So if noone can answear, I'll delete this post.

I'm trying to integrated asterisk with zanzibar. I barely succed because my asteriskConnector.sh is connected to my asterisk. I successfully started my cairo server (rserver, receiver ans transmitter) and my asterisk installations work perfectly.

I aleady try to look at sourceforge discussion to see if someone had the same problem but nothing.

Howerver, when I try to make a call (with the right extension) in order to try Parrot demo, my rserver.sh show me this error :

```
Could not process invite request.
Could not process invite.java.rmi.RemoteException: Method is not Remote: interface org.speechforge.cairo.sip.SipResource::public abstract org.speechforge.cairo.sip.SdpMessage org.speechforge.cairo.sip.SipResource.invite(org.speechforge.cairo.sip.SdpMessage,java.lang.String) throws org.speechforge.cairo.sip.ResourceUnavailableException,java.rmi.RemoteException
java.rmi.RemoteException: Method is not Remote: interface org.speechforge.cairo.sip.SipResource::public abstract org.speechforge.cairo.sip.SdpMessage org.speechforge.cairo.sip.SipResource.invite(org.speechforge.cairo.sip.SdpMessage,java.lang.String) throws org.speechforge.cairo.sip.ResourceUnavailableException,java.rmi.RemoteException
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:232)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:180)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.invite(Unknown Source)
    at org.speechforge.cairo.server.resource.ResourceServerImpl.invite(ResourceServerImpl.java:189)
    at org.speechforge.cairo.server.resource.ResourceServerImpl.processInviteRequest(ResourceServerImpl.java:225)
    at org.speechforge.cairo.sip.SipListenerImpl.processInvite(SipListenerImpl.java:446)
    at org.speechforge.cairo.sip.SipListenerImpl.processRequest(SipListenerImpl.java:123)
    at gov.nist.javax.sip.EventScanner.deliverEvent(EventScanner.java:223)
    at gov.nist.javax.sip.EventScanner.run(EventScanner.java:492)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

In my asteriskConnector.sh I got the following error :

```
Got an invite request
Received an unhandled SIP response status code (ignoring it): 183 : Session progress
Invite Response not ok
Got a dialog terminated event
```

I can't determinate why I got this issues. Can someone tell me why it does not accept invite ?

I am running asterisk and zanzibar on same ubuntu device.

Here's my set up:

```
[general]
langage=fr
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw
context=labo

[zanzibar]
type=peer
port=5090
host=192.168.142.7
secret=zanzibar
dtmfmode=info
canreinvite=no
```

manager.conf

```
[general]
enabled=yes
port=5038
bindaddr=0.0.0.0


[zanzibar]
secret=zanzibar
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
read=system,call,log,verbose,agent,command,user
write=system,call,log,verbose,agent,command,user
```

extensions.conf

```
[general]
[labo]
exten => 999,1,Answer
exten => 999,n,SIPAddHeader(x-channel:${CHANNEL})
exten => 999,n,SIPAddHeader(x-application:beanId|Parrot)
exten => 999,n,Dial(SIP/zanzibar)
exten => 999,n,Hangup
```

And my pbxconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd"> <beans>

    <bean id="main" class="org.speechforge.zanzibar.server.SpeechletServerMain"         init-method="startup" destroy-method="shutdown">    </bean>
            <bean id="sipService" class="org.speechforge.zanzibar.sip.SipServer"        init-method="startup" destroy-method="shutdown">        <property name="dialogService"><ref bean="dialogService"/></property>       <property name="mySipAddress">
                    <value>sip:cairogate@speechforge.org</value>        </property>         <property name="stackName">
                    <value>Zanzibar Sip Stack</value>       </property>         <property name="port">
                    <value>5090</value>         </property>         <property name="transport">
                    <value>UDP</value>      </property>         <property name="cairoSipAddress">
                    <value>sip:cairo@speechforge.org</value>        </property>         <property name="zanzibarHostName">
                    <value>192.168.142.7</value>        </property>         <property name="cairoSipHostName">
                    <value>192.168.142.7</value>        </property>         <property name="cairoSipPort">
                    <value>5050</value>         </property>
                <property name="mode">          <value>mrcpv2</value>       </property>         <!--property name="baseRtpPort"-->          <!--value>42050</value-->       <!--/property-->        <property name="maxConnects">           <value>50</value>       </property>     </bean>

    <bean id="dialogService" 
          class="org.speechforge.zanzibar.speechlet.ApplicationBySipHeaderService"
          init-method="startup" destroy-method="shutdown">
          <property name="instrumentation">
                 <value>false</value>
          </property>
          <property name="cloudUrl">
              <value>http://spokentech.net/speechcloud</value>
          </property>
          <property name="tempDirForPrompts">
               <value>c:/temp/</value>
          </property>   </bean>
    
    
    <bean id="callControl" class="org.speechforge.zanzibar.asterisk.CallControl"        init-method="startup" destroy-method="shutdown">        <property name="address">
                    <value>192.168.142.7</value>        </property>         <property name="name">
                    <value>zanzibar</value>         </property>         <property name="password">
                    <value>zanzibar</value>         </property>         <property name="disabled">
                   <value>false</value>         </property>     </bean>         <bean id="Parrot"
       class="org.speechforge.apps.demos.Parrot"
       singleton="false">
        <property name="prompt">
            <value>You can start speaking any time.  Would you like to hear the weather, get sports news or hear a stock quote?  Say goodbye to exit.</value>       </property>         <property name="grammar">
            <value>file:../../demo/grammar/example-loop.gram</value>        </property>     </bean> 
    

    <bean id="dtmfDemo"
       class="org.speechforge.apps.demos.DTMFDemo"
       singleton="false">
        <property name="prompt">
            <value>You can press any four digit extension on your keypad.  Say goodbye to exit.</value>         </property>         <property name="grammar">
            <value>file:../../demo/grammar/demo-dtmf.gram</value>       </property>     </bean>
    
    <bean id="callTransferDemo"
       class="org.speechforge.apps.demos.CallXferDemo"
       singleton="false">
        <property name="prompt">
            <value>Would you like to speak to Larry, Moe or Curly?  You can press any four digit extension on your keypad.  Say goodbye to exit.</value>        </property>         <property name="grammar">
            <value>file:../../demo/grammar/callxfer-demo.gram</value>       </property>
        <property name="pbxContext">
            <value>stooges</value>      </property>     </bean> 
    
    <bean id="Jukebox"
       class="org.speechforge.apps.demos.Jukebox"
       singleton="false">
        <property name="firstPrompt">
            <value>Hi.  Welcome to the speechforge Jukebox.  What would you like to hear Bob Dylan, Radiohead, Amy Winehouse, Rolling Stones</value>        </property>         <property name="laterPrompts">
            <value>Welcome back.  What would you like to hear next, Bob Dylan, Radiohead, Amy Winehouse, Rolling Stones</value>         </property>
        <property name="greetingGrammar">
            <value>file:../../demo/grammar/jukeboxWelcome.gram</value>      </property>
        <property name="playGrammar">
            <value>file:../../demo/grammar/jukeboxPlay.gram</value>         </property>         <property name="dylan">
            <value>file:../../../audio/jukebox/03RollinandTumblin.au</value>        </property>         <property name="amy">
            <value>file:../../../audio/jukebox/11YouKnowImNoGoodRemix.au</value>        </property>         <property name="stones">
            <value>file:../../../audio/jukebox/01FancyManBlues.au</value>       </property>         <property name="radiohead">
            <value>file:../../../audio/jukebox/08HouseofCards.au</value>        </property>         </bean>

        <bean id="implementationplatform" 
          class="org.speechforge.zanzibar.jvoicexml.impl.MrcpImplementationPlatform"
          singleton="false">    </bean>
    
    <bean id="jvoicexmlcore" 
          class="org.speechforge.zanzibar.jvoicexml.impl.MrcpJVoiceXMLCore" 
          singleton="false">    </bean>         <bean id="documentserver"       class="org.jvoicexml.documentserver.JVoiceXmlDocumentServer">       <property name="schemeStrategies">          <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.jvoicexml.documentserver.schemestrategy.MappedDocumentStrategy" />
                <bean
                    class="org.jvoicexml.documentserver.schemestrategy.FileSchemeStrategy" />
                <bean
                    class="org.jvoicexml.documentserver.schemestrategy.HttpSchemeStrategy" />           </list>         </property>     </bean>

    <bean id="grammarprocessor"         class="org.jvoicexml.interpreter.grammar.JVoiceXmlGrammarProcessor">        <property name="grammaridentifier">             <bean
                class="org.jvoicexml.interpreter.grammar.GrammarIdentifierCentral">
                <property name="identifier">
                    <list>
                        <bean
                            class="org.jvoicexml.interpreter.grammar.identifier.SrgsXmlGrammarIdentifier" />
                        <bean
                            class="org.jvoicexml.interpreter.grammar.identifier.SrgsAbnfGrammarIdentifier" />
                        <bean
                            class="org.jvoicexml.interpreter.grammar.identifier.JsgfGrammarIdentifier" />
                    </list>
                </property>             </bean>         </property>         <property name="grammartransformer">            <bean
                class="org.jvoicexml.interpreter.grammar.GrammarTransformerCentral">
                <property name="transformer">
                    <list>
                         <bean
                             class="org.jvoicexml.interpreter.grammar.transformer.SrgsXml2JsgfGrammarTransformer" />
                         <bean
                              class="org.jvoicexml.interpreter.grammar.transformer.Jsgf2JsgfGrammarTransformer" />
                         <bean
                              class="org.jvoicexml.interpreter.grammar.transformer.SrgsXml2SrgsXmlGrammarTransformer" />
                    </list>
                </property>             </bean>         </property>     </bean>     

</beans>
```

Comment: No way. You have read source code or hire someone who will read it for you. Read connector code.